# jQuery: get height of child element when parent height is 0px

Tags: jquery, height, parent-child

I have a div containing text which is inside another div displayed only under certain circumstances. The HTML for this is simple and looks like:

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'>
    Some text inside child div
  </div>
</div>
```

The styling would look like:

```
#parent{ display:none; height:0px; }
```

Using jQuery I would like to obtain the height of the child as I would if the div was outside the parent.

The following javascript returns 0, I wish for something around maybe 15.

```
var child_height = $('#child').height();
alert(child_height);
```

Comment: Works just fine for me. Make sure you're doing this _after_ document ready. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/EnZtq

Comment: working just fine http://jsfiddle.net/zjpav/1/

Comment: In addition to Matt Ball comment -> Returned 20 in FF and Chrome and 19 in IE 7.

Comment: More than likely #parent is actually `display: none` in your code in which case it would return 0.

Comment: please see update. I seem to have forgotten to add display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try all these and just working fine:

```
console.log($('#child').outerHeight());

console.log($('#child').css('height'));

console.log($('#child').height());
```

According to you edit:

```
var height = $('#parent').css({visibility: 'hidden', display : 'block'}).find('#child').height();

$('#parent').css({visibility: 'hidden', display: 'none'});

console.log(height);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zjpav/6/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily show the hidden parents then hide them after:

```
// .parents means it will search through all parents, not just first hidden
var hiddenParents = $("#child").parents(":hidden").show();
var childHeight = $("#child").height();
hiddenParents.hide();

alert(childHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zjpav/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
var child_height = $('#child').outerHeight();
alert(child_height);​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/kj8mg/1/)

Though on FF 10 your original code just works fine.

Update as per comment:

For hidden fields it will return zero, you can do something like this:

```
jQuery('#parent').css('display','block');
var child_height = $('#child').outerHeight();
alert(child_height);

child_height = $('#child').height();
alert(child_height);
jQuery('#parent').css('display','none');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/kj8mg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I notice you said: "inside another div displayed only under certain circumstances". If the parent div has `display: none;` (for example, if you hide it using any one of a number of jQuery functions, this is what it will end up as), then the height of the child will be returned as 0.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but I suppose you are right. There were some 'workarounds' to the problem, though, as you can see in the other answers. Thanks for your input!